# No update on API when receiving payments from other Blockchain.info wallets

Tags: api, blockchain.info

I am using the Blockchain.info API for an online shopping website. I have a problem in my Receive API: Payments from other wallets are working fine. Also, payments done by copying the address and sending payment to that address is working fine, but when a user sends payment from another Blockchain.info wallet using QR code (scanning the QR code via Blockchain App for Android), the index.php page remains as it is. Neither the .js file is called, nor the callback.php.

How can I still be notified of such payments?

Comment: EDIT : It doesn't work only if the user sends payment by scanning QR code from the Blockchain android mobile app. (haven't checked with iPhone)

Comment: You need to tell us what software or service you are using. As it is this question doesn't provide sufficient information to be answered.

Comment: I am using Blockchain API to Receive payments. Integrating this API with an online shopping website.

Comment: Yeah, well, how about you edit your question to put the information there instead of posting comments? Imagine that you are not familiar with your project, but hearing the first thing about it: You will realize that it is not clear what information you are scraping, what you have tried and so forth. Please provide more information, otherwise nobody will be able to help you, due to sheer lack of comprehensibility. – I have tried to get you started by editing some of the provided information into your post.

Comment: How can a .js be called, considering it runs clientside?

Answer (score 1):

Can't see what would be different from a QR scan.  If the correct BTC address is getting paid, it shouldn't matter if the address was copied, QR'd or hand-pecked.

I have an example of the callback from Blockchain's Receive API here:

https://github.com/damonp/simplebtcpay/blob/master/www/callback.php

Answer (score 0):

If each address you give to a user to deposit funds is unique, then you can check the balance of that address and get a response with the current balance & total deposited. You specify the confirmations in the URL of the api call.

Also are you using the Receive Payments API to receive payments, and the Wallet API for everything else? Because that seems silly.

Comment: Can you please mention the exact details of how to check balance and amount deposited?

I am not using Wallet API, just Receive API. My question is that if payments by copying the address and making payment is working, then why doesn't payment by scanning QR code work?